# Remove elements from pane when timer reaches 0?

Tags: java, timer, actionlistener, pane

I am trying to remove elements from a Pane when the timer reaches zero, more specifically a label and a text area. However, when the timer has reached 0 and I call this method I get this exception.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = AWT-EventQueue-0
```

Code:

```
ActionListener timeListener = new ActionListener() {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
    gameTime--;
    System.out.println(gameTime);
    if(gameTime == 0){
      endGame();
    }
  }
};
```

The endGame() method:

```
public void endGame(){
  timer.stop();
  System.out.println("Score: " + score);
view.gamePane.getChildren().removeAll(view.lblQuestion, view.tfAnswer);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an AWT Action-Event. You want to remove an Item from the JavaFX-Pane.
They run in different Threads.

When you want to access JavaFX from the AWT Thread use:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Your Access to Java FX
    }
});
```

But maybe you can use an JavaFX event instead of an JavaAWT event.